# Commit selected files to git and move to bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, bitbucket

i have created a repository in bitbucket and i have maven web project (eclipse ide) as  in below  structure

```
 project
   --src/main/java
   --src/main/resource
   --src/main/webapp
   .classpaht
   .project
    lib
```

i followed below link to create git repository and i pushed to project to but bucket, where as i have committed only java, resource and webapp files to git and pushed to bitbucket.

```
http://wangpidong.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/how-to-use-bitbucket-with-egit-in.html
```

but when i see in bitbucket i have .classpath, .project and lib folder added to the repository, which i never commited the files. i am new to git and bitbucket , i dont know how to fix, or am i doing it wrongly,, help needed

Comment: Might be you have used Team->Add to index, followed by commit, hence all the files/folders are added to the repository.  You can check the help available at github (https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)  for info on how to ignore certain files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a .gitignore file in your project home and add these lines into it:

```
.classpath
.project
lib/
```

by .gitignore file you tell git that ignore these files or directories

Comment: jsut wanna confirm the file naming, if i have two projects, then i will have two files named projec1.gitignore  and project2.gitignore placed /project folder ?

Comment: you shouldn't have project1.gitignore file. anywhere in your repository you can have a file named ".gitignore" but to apply its rules in whole project(repository) better to place it in the root of repository for more information see https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Answer (score 1):

Might be you have used Team->Add to index, followed by commit, hence all the files/folders are added to the repository.

You can check the help available at github (help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) for info on how to ignore certain files..

Comment: reposting my comment as answer